# WatchKit share data with MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, magicalrecord, watchkit, apple-watch

I use next code for setting CoreDataStack in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`(iOS app) and `awakeWithContext`(WatchKit) methods

```
lazy var sharedAppGroupDirectory: String = {
let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let appGroupName = "group.***"
let groupContainerURL = fm.containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier(appGroupName)
return groupContainerURL!.filePathURL!.absoluteString!
}()

var path = self.sharedAppGroupDirectory
path = "\(path)DataBase.sqlite"
MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed(path)
```

But calling Entity.MR_findAll() for iOS app return my rows, but same method for my WatchKit return `0 values`
Someone have any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: make sure your database add to targets is set with your watch kit extension and with your iphone

Comment: Yes, it's set, otherwise I could not be able fetch anything(watchkit would be crashes on line 'Entity.MR_findAll()')